# what if cond is signaled at the same time as timeout for pthread_cond_timedwait()

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, race-condition, condition-variable

In pthreads, what if the condition variable 'cond' is signaled and the time-out for `pthread_cond_timedwait()` happens at the same time?

does the pthread-standard define the behaviour?

is it thread-library specific behaviour for condition variables?

Answer (score 0):

Literally "at the same time" may not be possible and will be hardware dependent. Are you *really* concerned whether the implementation prioritises a timeout over the signal, i.e. observes the signal then checks to see if the timeout has happened too and then acts on the timeout instead even though it observed the signal first? (or vice versa). Concerns can come up in real-time embedded systems when timing is critical and prioritising interrupt processing is important (compilers such as CCS for the PIC have directives to manipulate ISR management for that purpose), but in a non real-time kernel as most Unixes are, the question should be irrelevant and it's worrying for the robustness of your application for you to be asking.